# Am I able to get Spotify on my Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch

Is there a way to get offline Spotify playlists on an Apple Watch?

Answer (score 2):

Spotify does offer an Apple Watch app. [Link.](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spotify-music/id324684580?mt=8)

Check out [this Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204784) on how to add or remove apps from your Apple Watch.

> All you need for Spotify to show on your Apple Watch is the Spotify app installed on your iPhone and an account with us. Just open it on your watch and log in to start playing!

To get offline songs and playlists you will need a Premium Subscription:

> Apple Watch allows your to add up to 2GB of local music to it directly. So you can add downloaded Spotify to your Apple Watch to listen them offline without a iPhone nearby. However, Spotify music are protected by DRM, only Premium users can download and save Spotify songs offline.

The [Spotify Premium page](https://www.spotify.com/is/premium/) lists the pricing options and lets you purchase a subscription. Currently, it costs 9.99 EUR/month for a single subscription.

In the future to see if an app is available for an Apple Watch you can go to the App Store on your iPhone or iPad and on the app page you’ll see a note saying offers Apple Watch app.

Comment: this doesnt work

Comment: @Antheloth what part of it doesn't work?

Comment: adding the music to the watch

Comment: @Antheloth is your account premium?

Comment: yes and i have offline playlists

Comment: @Antheloth That would be a great case to open a support ticket with the vendor and/or ask a follow on question with some details. Your question here was a "yes" / "no" question of is this possible. Asking a "how do I troubleshoot" needs some more documentation for us to help you further.